# Blend Animation Playing Issue

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8.1, blend

I don't know if I named the question right but here it is

First of all I am very new to Blend and never used it before in my life. I decided to make a simple animation today and things happened but not as expected.

I'm animating a button and the animation is just a simple 360 degrees flip on the Y axis. I created the animation for a specific button. It worked exactly how I wanted with this code

```
TiltAnimation.Begin();
```

However when I tried to create a ControlTemplate with this animation this happened. I need to click and hold the button in order for the animation to finish. I set the animation to play on a specific state: 'Pressed' (to be more specific it was pressed -> * which I suppose means 'from pressed state to any state'). Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something

Note: I'm experimenting on the windows phone platform.

If you need any code tell me in the comments

EDIT:Here is the XAML code from the page and from the App.xaml

Page code:

```
                    <Button Grid.Column="1"
                            Height="60" 
                            Width="60"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Background="White"
                            Opacity="0.8"
                            Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate1}"
                            Click="PlayButton_Click">
                    </Button>
```

App.xaml code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="360"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Grid.Projection>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition From="Pressed" GeneratedDuration="0">
                            <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                            </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualTransition>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="360"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="/Assets/Icons/Previous.png">
                <Image.Projection>
                    <PlaneProjection/>
                </Image.Projection>
            </Image>
            <Ellipse Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="4"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of the relevant XAML and C#.

Comment: @Dai I added the code, note that there is no c sharp code here

Comment: Where are you calling `TiltAnimation.Begin()`?

Comment: @Dai I called it when the animation was still not in a ControlTemplete but defined in the page. Do I still need to invoke the Begin method and if yes how to do that